# pygtk : saving the project file with suffix ".xyz"

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I created a `filechooserdialog` to save files,

```
filechooserdialog = gtk.FileChooserDialog("Save Project", None,
 gtk.FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_SAVE, (gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, gtk.RESPONSE_CANCEL,
 gtk.STOCK_OK, gtk.RESPONSE_OK))
```

Now I want to save file with a default extension, say `*.xyz`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the documentation on [`gtk.FileFilter`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkfilefilter.html). Create a filter for *.xyz and add it to the dialog with `filechooserdialog.add_filter()`.

---

**EDIT**:
If you want to ensure that the file has the proper extension, simply do this:

```
filename = filechooserdialog.get_filename()
if not filename.endswith('.xyz'):
    filename += '.xyz'
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. What i want here is, without typing the extension '.xyz' in the entry box in FileChooserDialog, the file should save with extension '.xyz' as default. That means I want to type the file name only, say 'sample', and it should automatically save with extension '.xyz', like "sample.xyz". Is it possible?

Comment: What happens here if the user types 'foo', which does not exist, but then 'foo.xyz' does exist?  It will silently overwrite it, which is not good.

Comment: Yes, of course you are right. I assume the OP was smart enough to figure that out, the question was about how to get a string from the file chooser in order to manipulate it :-P